# Pseudo Selector in Material-UI withStyles not rendering to page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

This is really weird. I an element that I need to add 2 pseudo selectors to: `::before` and `::after`. `::before` is rendering to the page, but `::after` is not. But the syntax is the same.

```
const styles = {
  Typography: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    lineHeight: '1.2em',
    height: '3.6em',
    textAlign: 'justify',
    marginRight: '-1em',
    paddingRight: '1em',
    '&:after': {
      content: 'test',
      position: 'absolute',
      right: 0,
      width: '1em',
      height: '1em',
      marginTop: '0.2em',
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    '&:before': {
      content: "'...'",
      position: 'absolute',
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the element that it is being applied to:

```
<Typography component="p" className={classes.Typography}> 
    {incident.incident_description}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The value for content needs to be [wrapped in quotes](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/v9.8.7/docs/json-api.md#property-content).

This makes so that it is compiled to the correct CSS representation with the quotes.

```
content: "'test'",
```

or

```
content: '"test"',
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use both single and double quotes

```
content: "'test'"
```

or

```
content: '"test"'
```

If you want to use a variable you can use a template string AND quotes

```
content: `'${yourVariable}'`
```

Also be sure to use a double colon `::` after `&`

so a full example would look like this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  const yourVariable = 'test';
  return (
    yourStyle: {
      //...
      '&::before': {
      content:  `'${yourVariable}'`
    }
  )
})
```